# How can I get the Name or DeveloperName value of a record type in a Case/CaseComments query

Tags: apex

I am trying to query CaseComment (and Parent Case) data and need the text value of the Case record type. I have tried the methods in several other answers but always get [object Object] rather than the record type name. My query is:

```
select id, ParentId, Parent.RecordTypeId, Parent.RecordType.Name, Parent.CaseNumber, IsPublished, CommentBody, CreatedById, CreatedBy.UserName, CreatedBy.ProfileId, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, CreatedBy.Email, CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, CreatorName 
from casecomment 
where createddate = today
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of the [Salesforce Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console.htm&type=5). It cannot output grandparent field data from a query. If you use something like the Apex Data Loader, Workbench, VS Code/Salesforce DX query commands, etc, you'll get that data as you expect.

[image: Workbench Query]

[image: SOQL Result Data]